# Add space above x-caption on D3js multiline chart

Tags: d3.js, charts, multiline, x-axis

I am trying to add space between xCaption and x-axis labels on D3js multiline chart but not able to. Also, how can I get rid of the last x-label (the one after 5).
[image]

```
const XCaption = svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height - margin})`)
        .call(xAxis)
        .append('text')
        .attr('x', (width/2) - 24)
        .attr('y', 25)
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(0)')
        .attr('fill', '#437495')
        .attr('font-size', '16px');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slide down your x caption by changing y:

```
const XCaption = svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height - margin})`)
        .call(xAxis)
        .append('text')
        .text('Sprints')
        .attr('x', (width/2) - 24)
        .attr('y', 30) // move your text down 5 more pixels
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(0)')
        .attr('fill', '#437495')
        .attr('font-size', '16px');
```

Those little ticks at the end are usually part of the axis domain. Use the css:

```
.x.axis .domain { display: none; }
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I have tried doing that, but in that case the xCaption gets hidden because of the chart height. If I increase the chart height, the chart spreads, but the space for the caption still remains the same.

Comment: thank you for you solution about the domain, it works like a charm.

Comment: If you're using the typical d3 margin setup, you'll need to add space to your `margin.bottom`.